# Выполняются ли асинхронные вызовы в js параллельно каждый в своем потоке?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Когда мы в js в браузере или в nodejs вызываем функцию

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("hello from callbak");
}, 5000);
console.log("hello from main");
```

то в стэке вызовов js дело дойдет до функции `setTimeout()`, она моментально(!) отработает, затем перейдет к `console.log("hello from main")` и потом callstack очистится.

Через 5 секунд же event loop поместит в пустой callstack функцию `console.log()`, и она тоже выполнится.

Все дело в том, что параллельно с движком V8, который и выполняет работу `setTimeout()`, рядом стоит webApi-модуль, в который передается функция `setTimeout()`, и фактически она выполняется именно там, а не в движке V8. Потом callback, который был внутри, ложится в callback queue, и оттуда event loop достает callback и отдает на выполнение в js-движок.

Если же мы вызовем не один `setTimeout()`, а сразу 5, то они все попадут в web api, и там они не будут выполняться последовательно, а запустятся все одновременно параллельно:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("hello from callbak 1");
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("hello from callbak 2");
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("hello from callbak 3");
}, 3000);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("hello from callbak 4");
}, 4000);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("hello from callbak 5");
}, 5000);

console.log("hello from main");
```

В результате в консоли я получу 5 записей "hello from callbak n", которые будут появляться с интервалом в 1 секунду.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значит ли это, что в web api модуле на каждый вызов функции создается свой thread? Или например есть пул thread-ов, в которых и выполняется работа?
Ведь кто-то же должен все-таки выполнять работу, а раз о

Comment: Они запустятся последовательно.

Comment: такого быть не может. Я сделал последовательно вызов setTimeout 5 раз, в первом 1 секунда, во втором - 2, и т.д. до 5. Если бы они запускались последовательно, то время между предпоследним и последним console.log было бы 4 секунды. А они все вывелись с интервалом в 1 секунду

Comment: Функция сеттаймаут выполняется моментально. Вы же сами об этом писали. Моментально выполнилась, положила калбэки на луп и они выполнились по очереди через 5секунд

Comment: setTimeout выполняется моментально в call stack. Фактически моментально она там не выполняется, а отправляется на выполнение в web api. А уже там она начинает выполняться, и выполняется столько секунд сколько указано в параметре функции

Comment: как-то все у вас намешано - последовательно, параллельно, одновременно. `setTimeout` синхронный, а не выполняется где-то параллельно в каком-то "webapi-модуле". Если вы посмотрите на реализацию `setTimeout` в nodejs - это обычный таймер и если взглянете на исходный код libuv - то увидите, что там используется pthread + sleep + timer (на юникс системах, не знаю что на виндовсе). Функции никогда не выполняются в движке V8, turbofan компилирует js в платформозависимый машинный код, который выполняется процессором

Comment: если он синхронный, то каким образом он не блокирует поток? Да, он синхронный, но он выполняется не внутри движка v8, а в библиотеке которая лежит рядом с движком, написанной на С++. И уже там создается отдельный поток, внутри которого происходит синхронный вызов setTimeout. Об этом и вопрос - для каждого такого вызова создается свой новый поток?

Comment: https://youtu.be/8cV4ZvHXQL4?list=LLh0EqNneN6FuEtvzKmPahTw

Comment: кто выполняется? `setTimeout` синхронный, колбек переданный в `setTimeout` асинхронный. Главный поток не блокируется потому что ОС переключается между потоками больше чем миллион раз в секунду, сохраняет архитектурное состояние одного потока, загружает из памяти состояние следующего и передает ему управление, это называется переключение контекста, движок хромиум использует пул потоков, а не создает каждый раз новый. @eri помогайте :))

Comment: Что то я не понял, как вы на основании того, что timeout отработали с разницей в секунду пришли к выводу, что они выполняются синхронно в своих потоках ? Самый распространенный способ делать таймеры - это некая очередь (например двунаправленный список) отсортированная по возрастанию необходимого времени срабатывания. Функция setTimeout должна взять текущее время, добавить к нему свой параметр задержки и положить ссылку на контекст выполнения в такой список. Движок в общем цикле работы, если наступило время события из вершины очереди выполняет его. Все. никаких потоков и ожидания не нужно

Comment: ok. А если это не setTimeout() а ajax-запрос? Или это какое-нибудь обращение в базу?
@overthesanity значит все-же setTimeout выполняется в каком-то отдельном потоке, отличном от главного?

Comment: вы как будто не понимаете к чему я веду :(( `setTimeout` выполняется в главном потоке и колбек выполняется в главном потоке

Comment: @ТимурБаймагамбетов Обращения к БД фактически сводится к работе с сокетом, соединяющим с БД, т.е. не особо отличается от ajax. Все уважающие себя программы, работающие с сокетами используют вызовы epoll/select ОС для ожидания событий на них. И они выставляют на этой функции таймаут равный времени до ближайшего таймерного события. Таким образом один поток спокойно может держать тысячу коннектов по сети и периодически отрабатывать таймеры. Собственно это и называется асинхронным приложением. Асинхронность и многопоточность совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: Простой пример https://pastebin.com/k6093Wzx показывает, что все происходит в одном потоке. пока не завершится длинный цикл более ни одного события не произойдет. А когда он завершится произойдут сразу все

Answer (score -2):

Для того, чтобы setTimeout() выполнялись последовательно, их нужно вложить друг в друга:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
console.log("hello from callbak 1");
setTimeout(function() {
 console.log("hello from callbak 2");
 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("hello from callbak 3");
  setTimeout(function() {
   console.log("hello from callbak 4");
   setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("hello from callbak 5");
   }, 5000);
  }, 4000);
 }, 3000);
}, 2000);
}, 1000);
console.log("hello from main");
```